# Why was brood parasitism known about in the middle ages?

Tags: biology

The Wikipedia article on [Cuckold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckold) indicates that the biological phenomenon of brood parasitism was known in the middle ages. (I suspect it may have been known in [other cultures](https://youtu.be/QlQNJxxIw6s?t=3m20s) as well, but I can't say for sure)

Although observing such behaviour doesn't require much in the way of advanced technology (though binoculars can help), I assume observing this behaviour would take a lot of time, and the birds (both hosts and parasites) are of little economic significance.

I tried searching about how brood parasitism was discovered, but I most of the hits about discovery were about whether or not the hosts discover the parasitism occurring.

Comment: Most likely a simple case of people observing nature while they were out doing other things, such as raiding birds' nests for eggs and seeing a strange (cuckoo) egg in the nest.